# dict pop does not free the memory

Tags: python, dictionary, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

Looks like garbage collector does not collect the values `pop`'d from the `dict()` in python 2.7 (did not try on python 3). Here is the example:

```
a = dict()

# fill the memory (dict)
for i in xrange(0, 9999999):
    a[i] = i

# Memory usage is about 600 MB
# try to free the memory
for i in xrange(0, 9999999):
    a.pop(i)

# print the dict and see it is empty
print "%r" % a
# prints: {}
# Memory usage is about 600 MB

import copy
a = copy.copy(a)
# Memory usage decreased to about 200 MB

import gc
gc.collect()
# Memory usage decreased to about 10 MB
```

Anybody knows why this happens and how to solve this memory leak issue?

Comment: how did you measure memory usage?

Comment: using `top` command

Comment: Why use `pop` rather than `del`?

Comment: @ivanK. `del` also behaves same.

Comment: `top` does not deliver accurate numbers, because memory blocks are not freed at once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no memory leak issue, since the memory is freed, when the dictionary isn't used any more. Dictionaries use internal tables to store the entries. These tables are not freed when using `pop`, because every key is mapped to a hash modulo size of the internal table. So the last existing key could lie at the end of this table.

To illustrate this, I'll use `sys.getsizeof`:

```
>>> a= {}
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
288
>>> for i in range(9999999): a[i]=i
... 
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
402653280
>>> for i in range(9999999): del a[i]
... 
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
402653280
>>> a = copy.copy(a)
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
288
>>>
```

Instead of using excessive `pop`s, you should create new dictionaries if necessary.

Comment: I repeated this experiment with a list `a=[]` and `a.pop()` and it looks like it DOES free up memory in that case, does that sound right?